# jQuery DataTables column definition for multiple data fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables with server side processing for my list.
But I have a problem: I want to display more than one column data from database in the same column (header). So, how can I define my column?

```
<?php
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'ass_id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ass_customer_id',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ass_customer_id',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ass_id', 'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ass_id', 'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ass_id', 'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ass_id', 'dt' => 6 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ass_id', 'dt' => 7 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ass_rec_letter_sent', 'dt' => 8 )
);
?>
```

In above code, I defined 8-th column as `ass_rec_letter_sent` but in this same column I have 2 more data fields to display, so I can't understand how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may employ [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option for that purpose. It accepts your cell data, cell data type, **entire row data source** and row number/column number as arguments.

So, for your target column you may make up combined field that will contain as many fields as needed referred by corresponding property name.

For instance, if the source data for each row of your table is an object, like:

```
{id: 'someid', name: 'somename', phone: 'somephone', mail: 'somemail'}
```

And you would like to merge `phone` and `mail` into combined column `contacts`, you may simply do:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  ...
  columns: [
    {title: 'contacts', data: null, render: (data, type, row, meta) => `phone: ${row.phone}, e-mail: ${row.mail}`}
  ]
});
```

Complete **demo** of this concept you may find below:

```js
//data sample that mimic response from your back-end PHP script
const srcData = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Steve Rogers', phone: '+1987270123512', mail: 'cap@avengers.org'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tony Stark', phone: '+1987987235143', mail: 'ironman@avengers.org'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Peter Parker', phone: '+1698701245121', mail: 'spidey@avengers.org'}
];

//datatables initialization
const dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'id', data: 'id'},
    {title: 'name', data: 'name'},
    {title: 'contacts', data: null, render: (data, type, row, meta) => `phone: ${row.phone}, e-mail: ${row.mail}`}
  ]
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="example"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks i will apply this but before that now i got another issue that it is showing "Showing 1 to 25 of 5,004 items (filtered from 5,006 total items)" but all data ( 5,006) load in one page. and no any error showing in console and checked parameter and length is 25 so why load all data?

Comment: If your original problem is solved by above answer, you may upvote and accept that, then post another question with another issue and I will gladly look into that

Comment: Now could you please tell me how I can search in this field? since I merge the first and last names, I cannot search. either I can use first_name to search or last_name